# sed: command garbled in SunOS

Tags: linux, sed, sunos

I am running following `sed` command to replace something in xml file.

`sed -e '/<AddName>/{ s;<AddName>;<ModifyName>;}' ${modified_name_file} > ${RESOURCES}/tempfile2.xml`

This works fine in Linux but fails in Solaris with following error.

`sed: command garbled: /<AddName>/{ s;<AddName>;<ModifyName>;}`

I am having hard time to figure this out. Is there any other way to do this in SunOS?

Comment: Can you try using the "usual" `s` syntax: `s/<AddName>/<ModifyName>/`? It's possible that using other letters is  a GNU extension, and the SunOS userland is notoriously very strictly POSIX.

Comment: The braces are quite unnecessary.  My suspicion is that Solaris wants a newline somewhere in between the tokens, but if you fix the syntax so that they are not necessary, the code should also be more portable.  Simply `sed 's/<AddName>/<ModifyName>/' file` will not modify any lines which do not contain a match on the regex `<AddName>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
sed '/<AddName>/{ s/<AddName>/<ModifyName>/;}' ${modified_name_file} > ${RESOURCES}/tempfile2.xml
```

Comment: `sed` remembers the last match and reuses it if you have an empty match, so `sed '/<AddName>/s//<ModifyName>/'` would accomplish the same thing; but of course, there is no need to specifically check for the match before replacing.  See my other comment above.